# A Windows phone 8.1 app doesn't scale right on my phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

So I have an app and I would like to upgrade it to Windows 8.1 so it has the latest version and I get all the updates/tools. When I tried to create one it went fine but as soon as I started debugging on my phone (the 640 XL) it shows only a part of the app.

I think this is because in windows 8.0 I had the option to scale 120% although I'm not too sure.

I'm kind of stuck here, I tried every option but it doesn't seem to work.
Here are 2 pictures to show you what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sp8H.jpg .

```
<Page
x:Class="App11.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App11"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid Background="#FF002E72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="640" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Margin="0,0.333,0,-0.333">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="638" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="401">
            <Rectangle Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="483" Margin="0,127,-3,0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="222,575,0,0" Foreground="White">
                <Span>
                    <Run Text="Ongestructureerd en onvoorspelbaar"/>
                </Span>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Span>
                    <Run Text="Onbekend terrein over meerdere domeinen"/>
                </Span>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="228,178,0,0">
                <Span Foreground="White">
                    <Run Text="Gestructureerd en "/>
                </Span>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Span Foreground="White">
                    <Run Text="voorspelbaar"/>
                </Span>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="228,293,0,0" Height="117">
                <Span Foreground="White">
                    <Run Text="Gestructureerd en onvoorspelbaar of  ongestructureerd en voorspelbaar "/>
                </Span>
                <LineBreak/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="228,433,0,0" Foreground="White" Height="120">
                <Span>
                    <Run Text="Ongestructureerd en onvoorspelbaar"/>
                </Span>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Span>
                    <Run Text="Onbekend"/>
                </Span>
                <Span>
                    <Run Text=" "/>
                </Span>
                <Span>
                    <Run Text="terrein"/>
                </Span>
                <Span>
                    <Run Text=" "/>
                </Span>
                <Span>
                    <Run Text="binnen"/>
                </Span>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Span>
                    <Run Text="eigen"/>
                </Span>
                <Span>
                    <Run Text=" "/>
                </Span>
                <Span>
                    <Run Text="domein"/>
                </Span>
            </TextBlock>
            <Image x:Name="image1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="92,153,0,0" Source="/Assets/niet-complex.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="image1_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="92,293,0,0" Source="/Assets/matig-complex.png" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
            <Image x:Name="image1_Copy2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="92,433,0,0" Source="/Zeer-complex.png"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="110,200,0,0" Width="100">
                <Span Foreground="#FFFFE699">
                    <Run Text="Niet"/>
                </Span>
                <Span Foreground="Black">
                    <Run Text=" "/>
                </Span>
                <Span Foreground="#FFFFE699">
                    <Run Text="complex"/>
                </Span>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="110,340,0,0" Width="100">
                <Span Foreground="#FFFFE699">
                    <Run Text="Matig"/>
                </Span>
                <Span Foreground="Black">
                    <Run Text=" "/>
                </Span>
                <Span Foreground="#FFFFE699">
                    <Run Text="complex"/>
                </Span>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="110,480,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,0.37" Width="89">
                <Span Foreground="#FFFFE699">
                    <Run Text="Zeer"/>
                </Span>
                <Span Foreground="Black">
                    <Run Text=" "/>
                </Span>
                <Span Foreground="#FFFFE699">
                    <Run Text="complex"/>
                </Span>
            </TextBlock>
            <Image x:Name="image3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="92,575,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Assets/uiterst-complex.png"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="110,622,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.63,0.259" Width="100">
                <Span Foreground="#FFFFE699">
                    <Run Text="Uiterst"/>
                </Span>
                <Span Foreground="Black">
                    <Run Text=" "/>
                </Span>
                <Span Foreground="#FFFFE699">
                    <Run Text="complex"/>
                </Span>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>

</Page>
```

Comment: Could you show the XAML code of this page?

Comment: @razor118 I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `XAML`, you set fixed `Height` and fixed `Width` on the root element.

Use the next links as a reference: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207025%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207042%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

There is a free video course on MVA "[XAML Deep Dive for Windows & Windows Phone Apps Jump Start](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/xaml-deep-dive-for-windows-windows-phone-apps-jump-start-8228?l=DjClR8Iy_3904984382)".

Comment: this is for Windows Phone 8, we're currently working in 8.1

Comment: Use "search" on resources I provided. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Change Grid declaration for that:

```
<Grid Background="#FF002E72" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
```

Right now it will get all available space (vertical & horizontal).
If you want to have adaptive layout you should use stretching. Adding to controls fixed size won't allow you to design adaptive/scalable design (in your case).

Comment: but I can't make an app that way because all the buttons, photo's, text, etc. wont be in the right place